# Impossible to draw because CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, fedora, cgal

I tried the following example of draw_polyhedron:

https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2draw_polyhedron_8cpp-example.html

but there is the following error :

```
Impossible to draw because CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined.
```

I tryied to add #define CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER but the error is still existing
[image]

Comment: Do you have QT5 install and libCGALQt5 compiled?

Comment: yes , I Installed it

Comment: unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/lib/ -lCGAL_Core
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/lib/ -lCGAL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/lib/ -lCGAL_Qt5

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CGAL-4.13/include

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding to ‍‍‍‍‍`.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER
LIBS+=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution - put the line:

```
 #define CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER
```

*before* all the CGAL includes in your `cpp` file.