# CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER

Tags: c++, qt, cgal, qglviewer

I'm trying to run libqglviewer [multiselection example](http://libqglviewer.com/examples/multiSelect.html) with .off file , but it show's the following problem :
Impossible to draw because CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is not defined.

So I added 
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER to .pro file 
it solves the existing problem but shows a lot of errors related to Basic_viewer_qt.h

```
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:146:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:552:29: error: ‘CGAL::QGLViewer’ has not been declared
   void attrib_buffers(CGAL::QGLViewer* viewer)
                             ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h: In constructor ‘CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::Basic_viewer_qt(QWidget*, const char*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool)’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:160:20: error: expected class-name before ‘(’ token
     CGAL::QGLViewer(parent),
                    ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:160:20: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h: In member function ‘void CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::attrib_buffers(int*)’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:557:13: error: request for member ‘camera’ in ‘* viewer’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     viewer->camera()->getModelViewProjectionMatrix(mat);
             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:562:13: error: request for member ‘camera’ in ‘* viewer’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     viewer->camera()->getModelViewMatrix(mat);
             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h: In member function ‘virtual void CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::draw()’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:624:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::attrib_buffers(CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt*)’
     attrib_buffers(this);
                        ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:552:8: note: candidate: ‘void CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::attrib_buffers(int*)’
   void attrib_buffers(CGAL::QGLViewer* viewer)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:552:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt*’ to ‘int*’
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h: In member function ‘virtual void CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::redraw()’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:727:5: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
     update();
     ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:727:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
     update();
     ^~~~~~
     QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h: In member function ‘virtual void CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::init()’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:733:5: error: ‘restoreStateFromFile’ was not declared in this scope
     restoreStateFromFile();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:734:5: error: ‘initializeOpenGLFunctions’ was not declared in this scope
     initializeOpenGLFunctions();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:734:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘QAbstractOpenGLFunctions’
     initializeOpenGLFunctions();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     QAbstractOpenGLFunctions
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:737:28: error: ‘EXIT_VIEWER’ is not a member of ‘qglviewer’
     setShortcut(qglviewer::EXIT_VIEWER, ::Qt::CTRL+::Qt::Key_Q);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:737:5: error: ‘setShortcut’ was not declared in this scope
     setShortcut(qglviewer::EXIT_VIEWER, ::Qt::CTRL+::Qt::Key_Q);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:737:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘QShortcut’
     setShortcut(qglviewer::EXIT_VIEWER, ::Qt::CTRL+::Qt::Key_Q);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
     QShortcut
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:740:5: error: ‘setKeyDescription’ was not declared in this scope
     setKeyDescription(::Qt::Key_E, "Toggles edges display");
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:774:11: error: ‘class CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt’ has no member named ‘camera’
     this->camera()->setSceneBoundingBox(CGAL::qglviewer::Vec(bb.xmin(),
           ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:774:47: error: ‘CGAL::qglviewer’ has not been declared
     this->camera()->setSceneBoundingBox(CGAL::qglviewer::Vec(bb.xmin(),
                                               ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:777:47: error: ‘CGAL::qglviewer’ has not been declared
                                         CGAL::qglviewer::Vec(bb.xmax(),
                                               ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:781:11: error: ‘class CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt’ has no member named ‘showEntireScene’
     this->showEntireScene();
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h: In member function ‘virtual void CGAL::Basic_viewer_qt::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent*)’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:800:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Draw edges=%1.").arg(m_draw_edges?"true":"false"));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:801:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:801:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:806:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Draw faces=%1.").arg(m_draw_faces?"true":"false"));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:807:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:807:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:813:9: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
         displayMessage("Flat shading.");
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:815:9: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
         displayMessage("Gouraud shading.");
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:821:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Mono color=%1.").arg(m_use_mono_color?"true":"false"));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:822:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:822:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:827:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Inverse normal=%1.").arg(m_inverse_normal?"true":"false"));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:834:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Draw vertices=%1.").arg(m_draw_vertices?"true":"false"));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:835:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:835:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:840:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Size of edges=%1.").arg(m_size_edges));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:841:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:841:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:846:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Size of edges=%1.").arg(m_size_edges));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:847:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:847:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:852:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Size of points=%1.").arg(m_size_points));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:853:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:853:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:858:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Size of points=%1.").arg(m_size_points));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:859:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:859:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:869:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:871:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:871:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:881:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:883:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:883:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:889:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:891:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:891:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:897:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:899:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:899:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:905:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:907:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:907:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:913:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:915:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:915:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:921:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:923:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:923:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:929:7: error: ‘displayMessage’ was not declared in this scope
       displayMessage(QString("Light color=(%1 %2 %3).").
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:931:7: error: ‘update’ was not declared in this scope
       update();
       ^~~~~~
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:931:7: note: suggested alternative: ‘QDate’
       update();
       ^~~~~~
       QDate
/usr/include/CGAL/Qt/Basic_viewer_qt.h:934:13: error: ‘CGAL::QGLViewer’ has not been declared
       CGAL::QGLViewer::keyPressEvent(e);
```

.pro file:

```
QT += xml quick gui opengl
CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS +=-DCGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
    multiselect.cpp \
    manipulatedframesetconstraint.cpp \
    object.cpp

RESOURCES +=

HEADERS += \
    multiselect.h \
    manipulatedframesetconstraint.h \
    object.h

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lQGLViewer-qt5

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lQt5OpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lGLU

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lCGAL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lCGAL_Core

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lgmp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64




unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../lib64/ -lCGAL_ImageIO

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../lib64



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib64/ -lQGLViewer-qt5

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib64


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib64/ -lCGAL_Qt5

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib64
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/lib64
```

any help? please

Comment: This post may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150670/impossible-to-draw-because-cgal-use-basic-viewer-is-not-defined

Comment: You should create  a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the right QGLVIewer. CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER is only required in the CGAL implementation of libQGLViewer, that is only supposed to be used in CGAL graphical stuff. Check you paths and avoid the ones containing CGAL.